# Remove a word from an array

Tags: java, android

I built a hangman game based on the tutorials here. It selects a random word from an array for the game. It is set up to not pick the same word twice in a row. The problem is that it will select the same word more than once while playing several games. Is there a way to tag or flag a word so after it has been used once, it wont be used again in the same gaming session?

I think I need an ArrayList but I can't figure out the code. I have been searching and trying things for a week and I just can't get it. I really have tried hard to find an answer on my own.

Full code

```
package com.slideproud.hangman;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;



public class GameActivity extends Activity {

//the words
private String[] words;
//random for word selection
private Random rand;
//store the current word
private String currWord;
//the layout holding the answer
private LinearLayout wordLayout;
//text views for each letter in the answer
private TextView[] charViews;
//letter button grid
private GridView letters;
//body part images
private ImageView[] bodyParts;
//total parts
private int numParts = 6;
//current part
private int currPart;
//num chars in word
private int numChars;
//num correct so far
private int numCorr;
//help
private AlertDialog helpAlert;

public GameActivity() {
}
//body part images



@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

//read answer words in
    Resources res = getResources();
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.words)));
//initialize random
    rand = new Random();
//initialize word


    //read answer words in
   // Resources res = getResources();
   // words = res.getStringArray(R.array.words);
   //initialize random
    //rand = new Random();
    //initialize word
   // currWord = "";

    //get answer area
    wordLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.word);

    //get letter button grid
    letters = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.letters);

    //get body part images
    bodyParts = new ImageView[numParts];
    bodyParts[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.head);
    bodyParts[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.body);
    bodyParts[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arm1);
    bodyParts[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arm2);
    bodyParts[4] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.leg1);
    bodyParts[5] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.leg2);




    //start gameplay
    playGame();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void playGame() {
    //choose a word
    int random = rand.nextInt(words.length);
    String newWord = words.get(random);
    words.remove(random);
    currWord = newWord;


//play a new game
//private void playGame() {

    //choose a word
    //String newWord = words[rand.nextInt(words.length)];
    //make sure not same word as last time
   // while (newWord.equals(currWord)) newWord = words[rand.nextInt(words.length)];
    //update current word
    //newWord.remove(0);
    //currWord = newWord;

    //create new array for character text views
    charViews = new TextView[currWord.length()];

    //remove any existing letters
    wordLayout.removeAllViews();
    //loop through characters
    for (int c = 0; c < currWord.length(); c++) {
        charViews[c] = new TextView(this);
        charViews[c].setText(""+currWord.charAt(c));

        charViews[c].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        charViews[c].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        charViews[c].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        charViews[c].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.letter_bg);
        //add to layout
        wordLayout.addView(charViews[c]);
    }


    //reset adapter
    LetterAdapter ltrAdapt = new LetterAdapter(this);
    letters.setAdapter(ltrAdapt);

    //start part at zero
    currPart = 0;
    //set word length and correct choices
    numChars = currWord.length();
    numCorr = 0;

    //hide all parts
    for (int p = 0; p < numParts; p++) {
        bodyParts[p].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

//letter pressed method
public void letterPressed(View view) {
    //find out which letter was pressed
    String ltr = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
    char letterChar = ltr.charAt(0);
    //disable view
    view.setEnabled(false);
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.letter_down);
    //check if correct
    boolean correct = false;
    for (int k = 0; k < currWord.length(); k++) {
        if (currWord.charAt(k) == letterChar) {
            correct = true;
            numCorr++;
            charViews[k].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
    //check in case won
    if (correct) {
        if (numCorr == numChars) {
            //disable all buttons
            disableBtns();
            //let user know they have won, ask if they want to play again
            AlertDialog.Builder winBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            winBuild.setTitle("YAY");
            winBuild.setMessage("You win!\n\nThe answer was:\n\n" + currWord);
            winBuild.setPositiveButton("Play Again",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            GameActivity.this.playGame();
                        }
                    }
            );
            winBuild.setNegativeButton("Exit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            GameActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    }
            );
            winBuild.show();
        }
    }
    //check if user still has guesses
    else if (currPart < numParts) {
        //show next part
        bodyParts[currPart].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        currPart++;
    } else {
        //user has lost
        disableBtns();
        //let the user know they lost, ask if they want to play again
        AlertDialog.Builder loseBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        loseBuild.setTitle("OOPS");
        loseBuild.setMessage("You lose!\n\nThe answer was:\n\n" + currWord);
        loseBuild.setPositiveButton("Play Again",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        GameActivity.this.playGame();
                    }
                }
        );
        loseBuild.setNegativeButton("Exit",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        GameActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                }
        );
        loseBuild.show();
    }
}

//disable letter buttons
public void disableBtns() {
    int numLetters = letters.getChildCount();
    for (int l = 0; l < numLetters; l++) {
        letters.getChildAt(l).setEnabled(false);
    }
}

//show help information
public void showHelp() {
    AlertDialog.Builder helpBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    helpBuild.setTitle("Help");
    helpBuild.setMessage("Guess the word by selecting the letters.\n\n"
            + "You only have 6 wrong selections then it's game over!");
    helpBuild.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    helpAlert.dismiss();
                }
            }
    );
    helpAlert = helpBuild.create();
    helpBuild.show();
}

public void setWords(String[] words) {
    this.words = words;
}
}
```

This is my error
Error:Execution failed for task ':HangMan:compileDebugJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   ...\AndroidStudioProjects\HangMan\src\main\java\com\slideproud\hangman\GameActivity.java
>   Error:(128, 31) cannot find symbol method get(int)
>   Error:(129, 14) cannot find symbol method remove(int)

These are my warnings

[errors pic](http://www.slideproud.com/errors.JPG)

Comment: I need a way to access the remove tag.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Use `ArrayList` like that:

```
Resources res = getResources();
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>;
words.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.words)));
//initialize random
rand = new Random();
//initialize word
```

then you can remove the after you get it:

```
private void playGame() {
    //choose a word
    int random = rand.nextInt(words.size ());
    String newWord = words.get(random);
    words.remove(random);
    currWord = newWord;
```

**Edit:**

you must change the scope of `words` so instead of:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    //the words
    private String[] words;
    //random for word selection
    private Random rand;
```

must be:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    //the words
    ArrayList<String> words;
    //random for word selection
    private Random rand;
```

and in your onCreate() you just initialize words:

```
Resources res = getResources();
words = new ArrayList<String>;
words.addAll(Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.words)));
//initialize random
rand = new Random();
//initialize word
```

Comment: I will try that when I get home.

Comment: I tried and I am running into the same trouble I've been having. I updated the question with full code.

Comment: @Dwood i edited the code to suit your GameActivity class. Try it and it should work.

Comment: On this line- int random = rand.nextInt(words.length);it says cannot resolve symbol 'length'.

Comment: @Dwood use words.size() instead because it's an ArrayList not Array

Comment: Sorry Hossam. I had two different versions and put your code in the wrong one. This works great now. I will figure out how to handle the error when I run out of words now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList provides the functionality of adding and removing anything from it.

You can try something like

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("any_word");
words.remove(i);   //i is the index of the word which you want to remove
```

Comment: I keep getting type errors. My words are a string, but the arraylist is saying java.utils I think. In your words.remove can I set it to the word that was just picked?

Comment: @Dwood ArrayList stores the contents using indexes so you have to pass the index of the word which you want to remove.

Comment: Is it going to be possible to do what I want with arraylist, or do I need to use something else?

Comment: @Dwood Yeah you can. Have you tried Hossam Khamis's code yet?

Comment: I am going to try it when I get home. To me it looks like it should work.

Comment: @Dwood You can ask if you get any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`Resources res = getResources();
        words = res.getStringArray(R.array.words);
        //initialize random
        rand = new Random();
        //initialize word
        currWord = "";`

to

`Resources res = getResources();
words = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.words));
//initialize random
rand = new Random();`

(thanks Hossam for that code)
so instead of a regular String array your words are stored in an ArrayList. Now that you have your arraylist of words you can change your playGame() method to look like this:

```
private void playGame() {

//this is the line that makes sure no words are reused, it removes the current word before a new one is picked
words.remove(currWord);

//choose a word
currWord = words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size());
```

And that is all, you should never get repeat words in your game unless you reload the words arraylist from resources. If there are any problems with this post the rest of your code so we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: I tried your code and got rid of all errors in the ide but got this in my logcat.java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: hmmm. Try changing ArrayList<String> to just List<String> everywhere it appears in the code, it should still work. I had the code written differently but one of the mods edited or something and I don't know what they're doing in the code. If not post your code and which line the logcat error is pointing to

Comment: Thanks for the help but I got Hossam's code to work.